# Subversion working copy newer than server because of rollback from backup

Tags: svn

So, my server administrator rolled back the subversion server from a backup.
My working copy is at revision 1534, but the server is now at 1525, which yields some problems:

```
$ svn up
svn: Revision 1534 not found
```

Of course, there is always the option to do a clean checkout, but is there an easier way to get my local working copy in sync with the server?

Comment: Were your modifications committed by the way? If not, you might have some problems and have to revert first (make sure to make a copy of the modified files first!). I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: They were committed, but is now lost on the server because of the rollback. I have the changes on my disk, and also an extra copy, ready to apply the changes once more.

Comment: Well, since nothing seems to work you will probably have to checkout everything again :/ Before, if you haven't already, you could still do a last check to see if everything is actually on the server up to revision 1525 (`svn log -r HEAD <URL>`) as you expect it to be...

Comment: Yes, everything up to 1525 is on the server, but missing 1526 to 1534 because the backup was at revision 1525.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check out again.

Your working copy is dead.

Your admins should really try to sync their back up on each commit or storing the commits as dumps via hook script

If you are using Windows/TortoiseSVN, please look at [Martins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874777/23264) below.

Comment: The sad thing is that this was actually a planned downtime, an upgrade that didn't succeed. I didn't get a notice, and they kept the server alive for 2 more hours after taking the backup.. :(

Comment: maybe your admins should learn some svnbasics.. point them to http://subtrain.tigris.org

Comment: Look at the answer from @Martin, it worked for me and helped me avoid a huge re-checkout.

Comment: @moodboom: I see your point, but this is a tortoiseSVN only behaviour. I updated my answer pointing to Martin

Answer (score 2):

There is way to do this I have just discovered - as long as you have a reasonably up-to-date version Tortoise SVN on your machine and your working copy was maintained by this version (i.e simply installing the latest Tortoise SVN wont work).

Go into the top-level directory and delete the .svn folder - this will remove all of the locally cached SVN information. Note: the .svn folder only appears in the top level checked out folder and is hidden.

Then checkout over the top of your existing local copy. Tortoise will then re-version the files, importantly leaving your modified files alone. You'll then be able to commit changes and update without any problems.

Comment: This causes each existing file to be re-"Versioned", and worked beatifully for me, saving me literally hours of checkout time.  Nothing else worked.  Thanks @Martin

Answer (score 2):

Your working copy IS NOT DEAD. Yes, you could check out again... but in my case that is over 20GB and would take very long time.

All I needed to take care of few files, which were newer on working copy, than on the server repository (also due to roll back).

What you can do, is to make a quick SPARSE CHECKOUT (check out only one directory) to temporary location. Next, from this partial checkout location, you take the hidden .svn file (the history of that directory), and place it to your problematic working copy (which holds newer history).

This will not affect your source text files, only give them older, but repository matching history. The Commit text since the rollback time is lost, but that is easy to retype.

After I did that, the svn worked fine and showed all the changes I made since the rollback time. Of course, you must COMMIT those changes again.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn up -r HEAD
```

or specifying another specific revision should work.

Comment: Have you tried with the specific revision number? `svn up -r 1525`?

Comment: This cannot work as svn up (on server) will always try to diff before pulling the update, however there is no such a revision.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any solution other than making a new checkout, and manually merging your uncommitted changes into your new working copy. Basically, your working copy comes from a alternate reality -- one where the server upgrade actually worked -- and I don't think Subversion has any provisions fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to us a few weeks ago.  I renamed my trunk folder, checked out a clean trunk and then manually copied all changed files from the crash date and beyond into my trunk so that I could recommit the changes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing also.

Answer (score 0):

At least for svn 1.8
svn update -r 1525
(as suggested by Michael Hackner) will work and will keep locally changed files untouched. Experienced the similar issue few minutes ago and solved it with this command.

To be verified what occur to files committed between 1525 and 1531.