# Tortoise SVN repository became corrupt - can we commit working copy to an older backup of repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, corrupt

Our tortoiseSVN repository unfortunately became corrupt today due to a disk glitch.

We have a good working copy based off revision 2897.
Our most recent backup repository is from revision 2848.

We would like to salvage as much as possible of the history, rather than start a new repository.

So, can we do this by committing the working copy directly to the older backup repository ?

Comment: Note that the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) describes a technique where a post-commit hook makes incremental backups. Now that you're bitten once, you might want to implement this. (Of course, we all know that, if you do this and it actually works, this will never happen again, but if you don't or if there's a problem with the way you do this, the next disk is certainly going to do this again. `:)` ) Oh, and, BTW, I'm with [thedev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981697/3981740#3981740) on this (`+1` from me), although SVN might complain about the local revision number.

Comment: Incremental backups are no defense, unless they're saved to a different disk. Consider using the svnsync to mirror changes to a remote warm backup, or something more sophisticated like the write-thru proxy functionality

Comment: @Mark: Who said those incremental dumps have to be made to the same disk? `:)` But, yeah, this is a important remark. Note that you could trigger the svnsync from a post-commit hook.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not missing anything, I do not see any problem in such a commit. Only that you will not have history details for the commits between the 2 revisions.

Comment: SVN might hiccup due to the working copy having a higher revision number than the repository. If so, you can remove the `.svn` folders from (a copy of) the working copy you have, and copy that over a fresh checkout. This, however, will lose any changes other than those made to the code (such as properties).

Answer (score 1):

[This happened to me as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693340/subversion-working-copy-newer-than-server-because-of-rollback-from-backup), I had to checkout a fresh copy, as svn got a real hickup when my local version was newer than the server.
When you have checked out a new copy, copy the files from what you had locally over your new copy (make sure you don't copy the .svn folders), and commit. You will loose history between 2848 and 2897

Answer (score 0):

You've lost your commit history, since revision 2848. Subversion working copies only keep local state....

Dependent on how you restore your repository you might also experience commit problems due to a mis-matching repository UUID. The [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.switch) command can be used to indicate a change of repository. Another option is to use tortoiseSVN to create a patch of the changes since revision 2848 and apply this to a fresh checkout.

Comment: Note that the patch will not have any changes other than to code (properties etc.), make sure you're not losing something important this way.

Comment: Your comment on property changes is well made. Let's face it impossible to fully and faithly construct a repository from a checkout. One of the selling points of the DVCS systems like Git is that they keep **all** history locally.